# What is the difference between list / array representation [] and {}?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the difference between :

```
dictionary = []
```

and

```
dictionary = {}
```

assuming dictionary has string contents ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What do you mean by "string contents" exactly?

Comment: I meant the elements of this list are string literals.

Answer (score 9):

In the first case, you're making a `list` whereas the other you're making a `dict`.  `list` objects are [sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) whereas `dict` objects are [mappings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).  Have a look at the [python types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types) page.

Basically, lists "map" sequential integers (starting at 0) to some object.  In that way, they behave a lot more like a dynamic array in other languages.  In fact, Cpython implements them as overallocated arrays in C.

`dict` map hashable keys to an object.  They're implemented using hash tables.

---

Also note that starting from python2.7, you can use the `{}` to create sets as well which are another (fundamental) type.  Review:

```
[] #empty list
{} #empty dict
set() #empty set

[1] #list with one element
{'foo':1} #dict with 1 element
{1} #set with 1 element

[1, 2] #list with 2 elements
{'foo':1, 'bar':2} #dict with 2 elements
{1, 2} #set with 2 elements.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is making a lot of sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

On python 2.x

```
>>> type([])
<type 'list'>
>>> type({})
<type 'dict'>
>>>
```

On python 3.x

```
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```